# Does Gray code exist for other bases than two?

Tags: math, gray-code

Just a matter of curiosity, is the [Gray code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) defined for bases other than base two?

I tried to count in base 3, writing consecutive values paying attention to change only one *trit* at a time. I've been able to enumerate all the values up to 26 (3**3-1) and it seems to work.

```
        000              122              200
        001              121              201
        002              120              202
        012              110              212
        011              111              211
        010              112              210
        020              102              220
        021              101              221
        022              100              222
```

The only issue I can see, is that all three *trits* change when looping back to zero. But this is only true for odd bases. When using even bases looping back to zero would only change a single digit, as in binary.

I even guess it can be extended to other bases, even decimal. This could lead to another ordering when counting in base ten ... :-)

```
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10
   20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 39 38 37 36 35 34 33 32 31 30
```

Now the question, has anyone ever heard of it? Is there an application for it? Or it is just mathematical frenzy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Have a look at the [Gray code article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) at wikipedia. It has a section on [n-ary Gray Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#n-ary_Gray_code).

> *There are many specialized types of Gray codes other than the binary-reflected Gray code. One such type of Gray code is the **n-ary Gray code**, also known as a **non-Boolean Gray code**. As the name implies, this type of Gray code uses non-Boolean values in its encodings.*

Comment: The French wikipedia page for Gray does not have it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness (as aioobe already gave the right answer), here's a C++ program that lists all the 168 2-digit gray codes for base 3 that start with 00 and marks the 96 cyclic ones. Using the [algorithm from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Constructing_an_n-bit_Gray_code), you can construct longer Gray codes easily for even bases. For uneven bases, you can change the program to generate according Gray codes.

The first cyclic 2-digit gray code found with this program is this one:

```
00 01 02 12 10 11 21 22 20
```

After changing the program, the first cyclic 3-digit gray found is this:

```
000 001 002 012 010 011 021 020 022 122 102 100 101 111
110 112 212 202 222 220 120 121 221 201 211 210 200
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Highest number using two trits
#define MAXN 9

int gray_code_count, cyclic_count;

bool changes_one_trit(int code1, int code2) {
  int trits_changed = 0;
  if ((code1 / 3) != (code2 / 3)) trits_changed++;
  if ((code1 % 3) != (code2 % 3)) trits_changed++;
  return (trits_changed == 1);
}

int generate_gray_code(int* code, int depth) {
  bool already_used;

  if (depth == MAXN) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXN; i++) {
      printf("%i%i ", code[i]/3, code[i]%3);
    }
    // check if cyclic
    if (changes_one_trit(code[MAXN-1], 0)) {
      printf("cyclic");
      cyclic_count++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    gray_code_count++;    
  }

  // Iterate through the codes that only change one trit
  for (int i = 0; i < MAXN; i++) {
    // Check if it was used already
    already_used = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < depth; j++) {
      if (code[j] == i) already_used = true;
    }
    if (already_used) continue;

    if (changes_one_trit(code[depth-1], i)) {
      code[depth] = i;
      generate_gray_code(code, depth + 1);
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  int* code = (int*)malloc(MAXN * sizeof(int));
  code[0] = 0;
  gray_code_count = 0;
  generate_gray_code(code, 1);
  printf("%i gray codes found, %i of them are cyclic\n", gray_code_count, cyclic_count);
  free(code);
}
```